# The extinction of the thylacine: could some still survive?

Tags: zoology, australia, cryptozoology

[image]

(Image comes from [Wikimedia Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Thylacinus.jpg))

The last known [thylacine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thylacine) died in 1936, and the species was officially moved from 'endangered' to 'extinct' in the 1980s.  Since the last living specimen died, there have been well over 3000 reported sightings, some with photographic evidence, of living animals.

Unlike many other cryptozoological animals, like bigfoot or Ogopogo, thylacines are (or were) real animals.

Is there any evidence that some animals still survive in the less populated areas of Tasmania or mainland Australia?

Comment: There have been cases of animals thought to be extinct that have since been re-discovered. Also, do you mean "Is there any evidence" or "Is there any reliable evidence"?

Comment: The more reliable the better.  As I pointed out in the question, there are some reports that are accompanied with video or photographic evidence, but they are self-admittedly of poor quality.  I would be more interested in paw prints, recovered hair, or fecal matter.

Comment: I think if there was good reliable evidence we would have heard a lot more about it. I can imagine the Aussie 'current affairs' shows doing one of their beloved hour long specials the minute a Tassie Tiger is captured.

Comment: While bushwalking in Tasmania some years ago, sitting quietly by a river, it occurred to me what a wondrous sight it would be to see a thylacine walk down to the water to drink. What a shame that such a beautiful animal is lost to the world.

Comment: @Craig:  I was thinking last night that *if* hard evidence of a thylacine were found and the location reported it would cause a lot of additional human activity in the area and probably causing additional stress to the surviving population.  There might be good reason *not* to report hard evidence, especially the location of that evidence.

Comment: Another thing has occurred to me:  *If* there were surviving thylcines, and their population was only large enough to barely sustain themselves, the inbreeding would probably cause genetic deterioration.  This, in turn, would make them more susceptible to afflictions like the [contagious cancer that has decimated the Tasmanian devil population](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2010/01/tasmanian-devil-cancer-mystery-solved/).

Comment: Oosterwal, I can imagine the scientists keeping it quiet, but the media? I doubt it, they are too desperate for the next big story (for this week).

Comment: What's up with the comparison to cryptozoology?  AFAIK I wouldn't consider the thylacine a cryptid.  We have plenty of physical evidence of it's existence, compared to actual "cryptids".

Comment: @JMac - you are correct that thylacines are not true cryptids.  The "cryptozoology" tag was included because the current existence of living thylacines is unknown and is often used as debate fodder when discussing cryptids like sasquatch or various lake monsters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There have been no recorded thylacine sightings on mainland Australia in modern (European) times. Tasmania is certainly its last hope, and that hope is very small indeed. What might be called "reliable" evidence such as tracks, scat and vocalizations were last recorded during searches in the 1960s, although these were inconclusive. Since then it's been reported sightings only, occasionally accompanied by dubious photographic evidence.

While it's likely that individual thylacines lived beyond the 1930s, it's essentially impossible, ecologically speaking, that any remnant population was large enough to sustain the species to the present day.

Comment: Are you talking about the population being so small they wouldn't be able to find mates, or so small inbreeding would be a concern?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of the concept of minimum viable population, which encompasses both of the things you mention: demographic and genetic stochasticity.

Comment: I thought genetic stochasticity would take several generations to occur.

Comment: Life expectancy seems to be less than 10 years according to Wikipedia.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm:  There is also the possibility that an encroaching human population could cause enough stress to keep mating couples from actually conceiving or carrying to term, even if there were enough couples to otherwise sustain or increase the wild population.

Answer (score 5):

The book *[The Last Tasmanian Tiger](https://www.bookdepository.com/Last-Tasmanian-Tiger-Robert-Paddle/9780521531542)* by Robert Paddle records several accounts as of thylacine sightings on mainland Australia in modern (European) times.

A naturalist named Cambrian, claimed to have inspected recently deceased remains collected from the Blue Mountains, west of Sydney, NSW in the 1880s. He inspected a second dead animal at a location concluded by that author to be the Flinders Ranges, in SA. Indigenous people in the same location in SA had "living memory" of live Tasmanian Tigers which, when you do the maths, date to the early 1800s - approx 1830s.

If you research historical newspapers you'll find three accounts of two different thylacines killed in the Blue Mountains in the 1800s. These are simple matter-of-fact accounts talking about Tasmanian Tigers getting shot.

With mainland accounts, however, you need to be careful of terminology. While we call them Tasmanian Tigers now, or Thylacines, they have variously been called Tasmanian Wolves, Hyena Opossums and other things - depending how far back you search historical records. Further, the animal we now call Spotted-tailed Quoll was previously called Tiger Cat - so accounts of "Tigers" in historical accounts are spurious and could equally refer to quolls or thylacines - you need to check carefully.

Aside from pre-1936 sightings on mainland Australia, we need to consider post-1936 sightings from both the mainland and the island state of Tasmania.

Perhaps one of the most credible mainland accounts is the case where the West Australian government commissioned Kevin Cameron, an Aboriginal tracker, to investigate continuous sighting claims coming from the southwest of that state, in the 1980s. (For context, see this [2004 article in Conservation Science](https://www.dpaw.wa.gov.au/images/documents/about/science/cswa/articles/90.pdf) summarizing 203 alleged sightings in southwest Western Australia investigated by the Department of Conservation and Land Management.) After several weeks, Cameron returned with a series of photographs showing what appeared to be the rump of a Tasmanian Tiger - the rest of the animal obscured by the buttress root of a tree, behind which the animal was digging in the dirt. Some of the photographs were published in New Scientist magazine.

> [image: Photo from New Scientist]

The story goes a little cold soon after, with some people taking the view Cameron feigned the shoot using a taxidermy, others suggesting the tiger is real enough but Cameron or a colleague shot it (which would have been illegal) and Cameron alleging something like a coverup of the truth of tigers being there in order to protect primary industries such as mining.

I had the fortune to speak to Kevin Cameron at length about this event only last year. I was the first person Cameron has spoken to publicly about the "Kevin Cameron Thylacine" since the 1980s. You can read my full account of my [analysis of this evidence](http://www.wherelightmeetsdark.com.au/examining-the-evidence/tasmanian-tiger-(thylacine)/cameron-thylacine/cameron-thylacine-detailed-analysis/), together with additional details of Cameron's story, at my website, [Where Light Meets Dark](http://www.wherelightmeetsdark.com.au). The conclusion I came to is that the body shape in the photographs **is** consistent with a Tasmanian Tiger - however the animal is probably larger than it at first appears. It seems the portion of the body in view is only a quarter of the animal - the upper half of the rear half. This suggests the animals feet are lower down, behind that buttress root, than the ground level in front of the buttress root - which is consistent with Cameron's story since the beginning, that the animal was digging behind the tree.

Moving on to Tasmanian accounts, the account which bears the most merit to me relates to the [Adamsfield thylacine](http://www.wherelightmeetsdark.com.au/examining-the-evidence/tasmanian-tiger-(thylacine)/adamsfield-thylacines/adamsfield-thylacine-identified/).

Researcher and author [Col Bailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Col_Bailey) recounts a story in his book [Lure of the Thylacine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29893996-lure-of-the-thylacine) that some hunters accidentally shot and killed a Tasmanian Tiger in 1990 near the ghost town of Adamsfield. Photographs were taken, Col obtained a copy of two photos and these show the animal's feet, one of which had a fresh wound on it.

Within 12 months of Bailey's publication of this account, a new party to the story came public via a filmed interview with the Thylacine Research Unit (TRU). This was ["Rusty" Morley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MubXnvNb41E&feature=youtu.be), ex-serviceman and professional tracker who stated the photograph was his but it related to a deceased animal he found under a rock overhang or similar, as opposed to it being killed.

At this point what interested me about this account was that although we had two different versions described as to how the animal died, what was *not* in contention was the fact (or allegation) that there was a recently deceased Tasmanian Tiger in about 1990 in Tasmania.

The story gets more complicated, however. I spent close to two years investigating the Adamsfield Thylacine. Long story short - a reader of my website happened to notice a video, published on YouTube, that was filmed in 1997 by the Australian Rare Fauna Research Association (ARFRA), based in Victoria. In that film, their founder, Peter Chappel, is seen investigating a large portion of Museum Victoria's thylacine specimen collection. One item in the collection is a skin and the skin's foot shows a patch where the fur is missing - essentially an area similar in appearance to the "wound" on the foot in the Adamsfield photograph.

The investigation continued and Museum Victoria graciously supplied new, high resolution photographs of that taxidermy specimen for my comparison with the photograph published in Bailey's book.

On first thought the case seemed cut and dried - that there was some mistake, or mis-allegation, and that the photograph simply showed a museum taxidermy. However the devil - or tiger, in this case - is in the detail: The second Adamsfield photo again shows one of the taxidermy's feet, but it is lying on top of yet another photograph, and that photograph shows an unrelated foot - matching Tasmanian Tiger in key features - and that foot is lying on the ground, outdoors.

This point is key and pivotal! My interpretation of these details is that:

- Someone (person unknown) took a photograph of an animal's foot - on the ground outdoors - to Museum Victoria
- Museum Victoria, for reasons unknown, was persuaded to produce a thylacine taxidermy
- The taxidermy was laid on top of the mystery photograph - and my interpretation is that this was done in order to compare the taxidermy's feet with the foot in the mystery photo
- And finally, a couple reference photographs were taken of the taxidermy's feet, including that one which shows a mystery photo under the taxidermy.

In other words:

- **The evidence suggests that a deceased thylacine was photographed outdoors, on the ground, in the early 1990s - and somebody obtained a photograph showing just one of the feet, then took that photo to a Museum where staff produced a thylacine taxidermy for comparison with that photo.**

To me, this account shows an incredible level of detail, accuracy and consistency with the allegation that in about 1990 there was a freshly deceased thylacine in Tasmania; it was photographed and - as the new insights show - at least one of these photos was taken to Museum Victoria (perhaps a little too close to home to go to the museum in Hobart?) for the purpose of comparison with a thylacine's actual foot taxidermy.

All this being the case, it would mean the Tasmanian Tiger survived 54 years in the wild - from 1936 to 1990 - without our being able to prove it's there. It's only been another 29 years since then - barely half that time again and I find it completely feasible the species still persists.

There are many more accounts, and many more details I have uncovered through my research that add to this picture, but for now, the Adamsfield thylacine remains one of the strongest items of evidence in the public domain for consideration.

I have answered [20+ similar questions from the public on a whole range of topics relating to Tasmanian Tigers](http://www.wherelightmeetsdark.com.au/research/tasmanian-tiger-(thylacine)-research/expert-discussions-q-and-a/chris-rehberg-via-quora/) - follow the link to read more.

**Addendum 5 Nov 2019**

I have now published an article on [an animal track line I discovered in Tasmanian which, after analysis, better matches Tasmanian Tiger than Tasmanian Devil](http://www.wherelightmeetsdark.com.au/examining-the-evidence/tasmanian-tiger-(thylacine)/prospective-tasmanian-tiger-tracks-found-in-tasmania/), on the basis of our current understanding of the tracks produced by these two animals. There is room to improve our research and understanding of devil tracks and I explain this in the article.

Comment: Postscript - it seems various aspects of Paddle's book may be contentious and open to debate, including his accounts of Cambrian examining freshly deceased thylacines. That said, the newspaper reports of tigers killed in the Blue Mountains stand separately, and the real significance across the above accounts lies in the Tasmanian account.

Comment: Please provide some more references for your claims - e.g. links to the accounts in the newspapers you talk about, some idea of who Col Bailey and Rusty Morley are, links to the YouTube video you talk about, etc.

Comment: You spend a lot of the answer discussing the Adamsfield Thylacine, but it isn't clear why. How does it advance the case that thylacine are alive now?

Comment: [What I am about to say will sound unfair, because the existing answer fails to meet our standards - it was posted in the early days before we had finished establishing them.] This answer needs a summary, and it seems to be: "There have been reports of sightings around 30 years ago, but the evidence is limited and disputed. I think it is feasible that the species exists, but it is considered very unlikely."

Comment: @Oddthinking thanks for your feedback and comments. I've added explanatory text clarifying who Col Bailey and Rusty Morely are and included links to their profile, book and the video interview mentioned. I've clarified how the Adamsfield evidence supports the view the thylacine persisted to 1990.

Comment: @Oddthinking In response to your summary: the evidence I present in this answer is a result of my own research, published only last year. If it is "considered very unlikely" by a majority it is only because my website has limited reach and few professional scientists are open-minded to the proposition the tiger persisted that long. These points do not negate the veracity of the evidence, and this is why I present an alternative answer to the question. The link is in the article to my full analysis if anyone wishes to check my interpretation themselves (as any other source would be referenced).

Comment: Thanks for your edits. Appreciated. As skeptics, we need to consider the other option to professional scientists being closed-minded. They may have open-mindedly considered the arguments and found them lacking. There are [reasons](https://slate.com/technology/2013/09/fake-wildlife-sightings-probably-extinct-night-parrot-thylacine-auk-and-ivory-billed-woodpecker.html) to [distrust](https://slate.com/technology/2013/09/fake-wildlife-sightings-probably-extinct-night-parrot-thylacine-auk-and-ivory-billed-woodpecker.html) Kevin Cameron's photos which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Your link to an opinion piece suggesting it's generally believed Cameron used a taxidermy or found a different animal is one thing. My article which actually investigates those allegations of shifting shadows is a little more methodical and post-dates those opinions. In any case, I have now added a link to an article in the journal Conservation Science discussing 200+ alleged thylacine sightings originating from southwest Western Australia, investigated by the Department of Conservation and Land Management, which provides context for Cameron being contracted by the government to investigate.

Comment: PS. The answer here is only a summary description of two claims, but I have gone to those which in my opinion hold the greatest merit. All I can say about the Cameron photos is that the animal depicted within is consistent in morphology with a thylacine and people have probably incorrectly assumed the animal to be smaller than it is. To me, the Adamsfield case holds additional weight precisely because nobody is debating the thylacine lived in Tasmania in recent times.

Comment: I'm highly suspicious of any claim of people having photographed an extinct animal and the only producing (often blurry) photographs of body parts rather than the entire animal. Way too easy to fake. As to the museum "producing a specimen" it probably is on public display...

Comment: I would suggest it is perfectly right to be skeptical. However here is a scenario under which the Adamsfield events might have transpired: animal is killed, photographs taken - possibly including full body as well as body parts. Third party is aware of event and clandestinely obtains photo of foot only. As such, third party may not go public but does want to check veracity of the photo. Travels interstate to avoid local suspicion and conducts comparison with taxidermy. That taxidermy was not available for public access the way it is being handled in the photos - check the link for photos.

Comment: I looked at some of the other video sightings? What would your assessment be of a possible point mutation causing it to lose its stripes?

Comment: @Joshua - I am no expert in genetics - not even a rookie, so can't really comment. However I can say the Thylacine mummy found at "Thylacine Hole" (a cave near Mundrabilla Station) had its fur intact, including stripes - suggesting to me the Thylacine on the mainland was near enough to identical to the Thylacine in Tasmania. While we see abberant colouration in some mammals (search my site for an all-white Eastern Quoll), these are typically odd individuals rather than new morphs.